# upload data from excel to sharepoint list using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to upload data from a excel to a sharepoint list. The structure of the excel and the list are same.

The user will enter the data in the excel and then give the path of the file in the input box present in the page. Now instead of uploading the whole excel file into a document library the code will read the file and update the list with the data present in the excel file. I am using JQuery in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to help with this. I have no idea how you are managing to use jQuery in an Excel spreadsheet, but if you've really solved that part, then maybe SPServices can help with the actual writes.

Is there any reason you aren't simply using the Office capabilitiy to publish to SharePoint directly?

Comment: Good reference. I use this library and it's basically awesome.

Comment: I will look into the SPServices. I am not using JQuery in Excel spreadsheet. I have a portal in sharepoint developed using JQuery. The site will be used by other engagements to pull the relevant data. This data is analysed and formatted in Excel so I am thinking if I can straight way upload the data from the Excel to the sharepoint as the person who work on this data have very basic knowledge on Excel and I don't have confidence on him.

Comment: You should look at the OOB functionality to keep a SharePoint list and an Excel spreadsheet in synch. I don't think that jQuery enters into this at all.

Comment: Oh, and pixelbobby: Thanks. Glad you like my SPServices library!

Comment: Thanks Marc. The OOB functionality is the best solution that I can implement now.